# How to remove numbers from array using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am not sure if this is right? I want to remove numbers from array(docs).

```
for (var i = 0; i < clean.length; i++) {

    var regex = /([^0-9]*)$/;

    console.log(regex.test(clean));

    tags.push(clean);

    if (regex.test(clean[i])) {

        clean.splice(i, 1);

    }
}
```

Comment: Post `clean` array

Comment: {"0", "1", "a", "c", "3"}

Comment: That's an object, are you sure you're working with an array here?

Comment: yeah, if it is an array. how do we deal with it?

Comment: Please update the source code in your question that will give myself and others something to work with rather than parts of it. Without having the complete source we can only make assumptions which don't always lead to a solid/correct answer, reproducing the problem will get you the help you want.

Comment: One reason your code does not work is that you're modifying the array as you loop through it.  Think of what happens to your iterator when you remove an element from the list.  You could iterate backward, but the `filter`-based solution supplied will be cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `clean` an array. You can do use `Array#filter` to check if current element is an array.

```js
var clean = ["0", "1", "a", "c", "3"],
    tags = [];
clean = clean.filter(function(v){

   return ! ( /[0-9]/g ).test(v);

});

tags = tags.concat(clean);

console.log( tags );
```

Comment: okay but tags is also an array. I need to put it in that array.

Comment: @ilovejava, do you want to the filtered array (only alphabet) into tags?

Comment: yeah. that's what i want

Comment: @ilovejava, confirm the change.

Comment: Very and simple! if you don't want to use `return` you could replace that line with `if(!( /[0-9]/g ).test(v)){tag.push(v);}` but still **+1** for simplicity.

Comment: @NewToJS, you're right, but I am assuming OP needs `clean` as well. But neat solution!

Comment: @AdamAzad You might be correct but I thought the reason for building a new array might be so the original `clean` can be kept unmodified. Having two arrays the same just doesn't make sense, why use `tag` if `clean` is exactly the same. That's my thoughts and reason for my comment above.

Comment: @NewToJS : in the same case how do we remove special characters like colon, comas. Suppose if I have a string like "check:one", "chekc-two". How do I remove those using regex.

Comment: @AdamAzad : in the same case how do we remove special characters like colon, comas. Suppose if I have a string like "check:one", "chekc-two". How do I remove those using regex.

Comment: That is a different/new question. I am sure if you research your question you will find multiple answers how to do exactly that.